# What is the best way to arrange variables and methods in a class?

Tags: class, variables, methods, coding-style, readability

I usually arrange my variables and methods like this:

```
class MyClass {
    // public variables
    // public methods
    // private methods
    // private variables
}
```

I want to know what is the best arrangement for defining functions and variables in terms of readability?

EDIT: Also what about enum and class definitions within the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
class MyClass {
    // private fields
    // public methods
    // private methods
}
```

You shouldn't have any public fields. Use properties instead.

[StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) has a [set of rules on suggested code order](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/orderingrules.htm). See [SA1201](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1201.htm):

> Within a class, struct, or interface, elements must be positioned in the following order:
>
> - **Fields**
> - Constructors
> - Finalizers (Destructors)
> - Delegates
> - Events
> - Enums
> - Interfaces
> - Properties
> - Indexers
> - **Methods**
> - Structs
> - Classes

and [SA1202](http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1202.htm):

> To comply with this rule, adjacent elements of the same type must be positioned in the following order by access level:
>
> - **public**
> - internal
> - protected internal
> - protected
> - **private**

If you use StyleCop it will warn you when you break these rules.

Comment: Why are private fields above public methods? I always thought that when someone looks at a class definition they would be more interested in the public methods rather than the private fields. Having private fields on top would mean the reader would have to ignore a section of the code and scroll down to see what they're interested in.

Comment: Someone interested only in the public interface can read the class documentation. Anyone that needs to look at the source code is interested in the implementation. Also, some tools will automatically add new methods at the bottom of the class. If you put private fields at the bottom, they can move into the middle.